# Live video broadcasting SDK

Tags: android, broadcast, live-streaming, android-broadcast

I need to develop App for live broadcasting video to AWS.

From back-end I get link (like: rtp://111.11.11.1:5000 ) and need to stream to it. By stream i mean: broadcast video from device camera to this link. I have no experience in streaming, so decided to use some SDK.
I've spent a lot of time googling it, but didn't find anything useful (some SDKs support only *RTMP*, or *RTSP* links, some are not alive anymore, etc).

The only workable solution for now in **Wowza**, which is quit expensive.

Can somebody recommend some free, or not expensive SDK, or any solution?

Comment: just a suggestion: have you tried the exoplayer sdk?

Comment: yes, but it allows only watch broadcast, and i need to stream from device-camera to the link